# Enumerating un-labeled Hasse diagrams.

Tags: combinatorics

As a set of homework problems I've been tasked with figuring out haw many posets can be listed that satisfy some given condition.

For example: *how many Join semilattices are there with 5 elements?*

Going with this example, I've been going through all the possible "forms" of the Hasse diagrams that fit the condition.

Now, I need to figure out how many ways there are to label each diagram.

Take the following Hasse diagram:

```
    .
   / \
  .   .
  |   |
  .   .
```

Does anyone have a general strategy that I can use to enumerate the labelings. I'm not necessarily looking for a closed form formula or a recurrence or anything, just some tips on how to think about it. Although having a recurrence/formula would obviously be useful in providing insight.

**Edit:**

The comments state that the answer can be found with: `n! / the number of symmetries`, but what about the following diagram?

```
    . 
  ....
```

I didn't draw the lines, but it's the 5 element poset with 4 symmetries.

I'm pretty sure the answer is 5 here. You have 5 different choices for the max element but beyond that the ordering doesn't matter.

However, I see 4 symmetries in the graph and 5! / 4 = 30.

Can someone explain?

Comment: What do the labelings have to satisfy? If they are linear extensions then there's a recurrence for that that should be easy to apply by hand for a five element poset I think.

Comment: @Matt: I think it's most reasonable to suppose the labelings to be distinct up to poset automorphisms.

Comment: @Eric then it should just be $n!$ divided by the number of automorphisms.

Comment: @Matt:  I'm still very new to the terminology, but I believe that Eric is correct in his assumption, which i am interpreting as stating that I'm looking for all the distinct ways to label the diagram that form a *unique* poset.   How do I figure out the number of automorphisms, then?

Comment: @LukeP I can tell you that poset has two automorphisms. I don't know any reasonable methods that work in general, but I would guess most of these posets don't have very many.

Comment: As Matt says, determining automorphisms (symmetries) is not a particularly exact science, you just kind of look sections of a graph that you can interchange with one another without changing the overall poset structure.

Comment: @EricStucky So the automorphisms are the two "legs" of the graph then, right? Could you explain why 5! / 2 gives me my answer here? It still seems like a magic formula to me.

Comment: As I work through the more trivial examples (the ones I know the answer to), that formula always seems to work! I guess I'm just looking for a proof though.

Comment: Working through more examples is making the formula's correctness more intuitive now!

Comment: I'm not sure if what I wrote is what you mentioned by a 'proof'. Proving the formula $|\text{Label}(P)/\text{Aut}(P)| = |P|! /|\text{Aut}(P)|$ would require a little bit of group theory. But on a case-by-case basis, you can make these kinds of arguments. [ Side note: I'm glad that you were working examples while I was writing my answer! In my experience, this is the sign of a strong student :) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the comment in the comments, which to me seems like a reasonable answer to the entire question:

Without appealing to group theory, we can see by elementary means that the diagram you listed above must have 60 distinct labelings.

- Some element must be the maximum element. There are $5$ choices.
- Some pair of remaining elements must be in the middle layer. However, since we cannot distinguish the "left" from the "right" leg, it only matters which two elements we put into this pair, not which one goes where. So there are $(4\times 3)/2=6$ choices.
- Finally, we must put the last two elements in the remaining layer. This time, though, it does matter which one we put in the right leg and which we put in the left; the labelled poset can distinguish between them based on where we put the elements in the middle layer.  There are $2\times 1=2$ choices.

All of these choices are indepenedent, so you have $5\times 6\times 2=60$ distinct labelings.

(If the last step makes you uncomfortable, your concerns may be assuaged by being a bit more explicit. Without loss of generality, suppose that your label set is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and in step 2, put the smaller label in the left leg. Now *you* can also distinguish between right and left without appealing to the geometry.)

Comment: Can you see my edit?

Comment: @LukeP: You missed some of the symmetries: there is the 1 do-nothing symmetry [you found it], then there are 6 ways to interchange two elements, 8 ways to cyclically permute three, 6 ways to cyclically permute four [you found two], and 3 ways to interchange two pairs of two elements [you found one], for a total of 24. (Easier, you cannot distinguish between putting of the non-maximal elements, so you can permute them freely; each permutation is a symmetry.)

Comment: Ah, so I misunderstood the definition of symmetry. its not "the number of Identical looking legs" its the number of ways you can swap the legs around without changing the graph? That would make sense because I was only looking at cases with 1-2 identical segments. So, would it be true that, where L is the number of identical segments, L! is the divisor I am looking for?

Comment: @Lukep it's a lot more complicated than that. An automorphism is a way to permute the vertices while still preserving the ordering. So it's a function $f$ from the vertices to the vertices satisfying $f(x)\leq f(y)$ if and only if $x\leq y$.

Comment: @LukeP: In theory it is a lot more complicated than that, but in practice, most symmetries you would run into for small posets are independent choices of leg-swaps. (You've only seen 'one choice leg-swap' cases, but imagine that you put little Vs on the bottom of your example graph, and you now have the choice to swap the top two or not, and independently, to swap the little legs or not.)